# Some variables not being returned correctly from inside a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope

I have declared a few functions in the main section of the program, which get used in one of my functions. guessList is being returned with the modified information correctly, but guess is not.

I am able to force it to update correctly if I declare guess as global inside userGuess(), but I know that's bad practice. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

```
incorrectGuesses = 0
guessList = []
guess = ""

def userGuess():
    #Get user input for their guess
    guess = input("What do you think the organism is? ")
    #check for special characters
    specialCharacters = "!@#$%^&*()-+?_=,<>/"
    if any(c in specialCharacters for c in guess):
        print("Please do not inclue any special characters in your guess")
        #for now we will assume that the user follows the rules and doesn't include any special characters the second time
        guess = input("What do you think the organism is? ")
        print("Awesome, you guessed", guess, "which is fine")
        guessList.append(guess)
        return guess, guestList
    else:
        print("Awesome, you guessed", guess, "which is fine")
        guessList.append(guess)
        return guess, guessList
userGuess()
```

Regardless of if the user uses special characters or not, it consistently adds the guess to the guess list correctly, but does not update the guess variable outside of the function.

If I declare the guess variable as global within the function, it will update outside the function correctly. I've tried passing the guess argument into the function as a parameter before returning but it had no effect.

Comment: [How to use a global variable in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/423379)

Comment: Also, note you are ignoring the return values. `guess, guessList = userGuess()`. You could do this instead of using `global`.

Comment: Also, `guessList.append(guess)` works because you are not reassigning the variable - you are modifying the object it points to, so `global` is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Values returned from a function are not automatically copied into the caller's context, as you seem to expect.

You need to **capture** the returned values when you call the function:

```
guess, guessList = userGuess()
```

Answer (score 0):

the guess variable inside which you get input in the function is different from the the variable guess you have created outside of the function eventhough you have named it the same, as the guess in side the function has local scope and can only be used inside the function .  it cannot have any effect outside of the function . you must understand that both the variables are not same . so, reassigning values for a variable with global scope inside a function does not work .but the list is updated properly as list is a mutable data type and here you are not reassigning , but mutating the value . first change the name of the variable inside which you are getting input in the function to avoid cunfusion and then call the function inside the global guess  and guesslist variable like so:

```
guess, guessList = userGuess()
```

Hope this helped